# Bundler could not find compatible version of gem despite it being there?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I don't understand this error I receive when I run `bundle install`:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.16.2)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
```

If I have bundler version `1.16.2`, why is it not considered to meet the `~> 1.0.0` criteria?

Comment: Is that the entire error message? It could be that other gems are producing the above message. If so- can you post the full error message?

Comment: because `~>` will only increment the TEENY version in that case . Essentially this mean >= 1.0.0 and < 1.1

Comment: It is. `rails` is the first gem it tries to install.

Comment: @engineersmnky interesting! You should write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `~>` notation allows for the delineation of the incrementation whereby the least significant digit is allowed to differ from the specification.

So in this case `~> 1.0.0` means any version that is >= 1.0.0 and < 1.1.

However a notation of `~> 1.0` would mean any version >= 1.0 and < 2.0

In your case `1.16.2` is clearly greater than `1.1` and thus fails the requirement set forth

Comment: And what is the solution to this problem?

Comment: @cryptic0 one could use `gem install bundler -v '~> 1.0.0'`; however the question posed was "If I have bundler version 1.16.2, why is it not considered to meet the ~> 1.0.0 criteria?" Which is why I answered the way I did.

Comment: I had been getting a similar error, except it was expecting version 1.16.  So on a whim, I changed the gem file and updated the version to what I have on my system (2.0.1) and that did the trick.  For the record, I am trying to install a jekyll theme called Ed.